# Need an example showing how to apply a binary function to all pairs of elements of two lists

Tags: haskell

```
map2_List :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
map2_List f [] _ = []
map2_List f (a:as) bs = map (f a) bs ++ map2_List f as bs
```

This is an example to apply a binary function to all pairs of elements of two lists. I feel confused why this apply every `(f a)` to `bs` instead of apply `f` to each element of `[a]` and `[b]` respectively.

Could anyone give an example of how it works?

Comment: Have you already [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51680886/1126841)?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Could you give an example of how you would "apply `f` to each element of `[a]` and `[b]` respectively" in order to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never deconstruct the `b` list, so every time you call `map (f a)`, that's being applied to *each* value of `bs`. For example,

```
map2_List (+) [1,2,3] [10,11,12] == map (+ 1) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map2_list (+) [2,3] [10,11,12]

                                 == map (+ 1) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map (+ 2) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map2_List (+) [3] [10,11,12]

                                 == map (+ 1) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map (+ 2) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map (+ 3) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map2_List (+) [] [10,11,12]

                                 == map (+ 1) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map (+ 2) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map (+ 3) [10,11,12] ++
                                    []

                                 == [11,12,13] ++
                                    map (+ 2) [10,11,12] ++
                                    map (+ 3) [10,11,12] ++
                                    []

                                 == [11,12,13] ++
                                    [12,13,14] ++
                                    map (+ 3) [10,11,12] ++
                                    []

                                 == [11,12,13] ++
                                    [12,13,14] ++
                                    [13,14,15] ++
                                    []

                                 == [11,12,13,12,13,14,13,14,15]
```

A much more compact definition would use the `Applicative` instance for lists:

```
map2_List f as bs = f <$> as <*> bs
```

---

The version you seem to be thinking of would deconstruct both lists in parallel:

```
map2_ZipList f [] [] = []
map2_ZipList f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : map2_ZipList as bs
```

which is already defined as `zipWith`:

```
map2_ZipList = zipWith
```

Comment: ... or `zipWith`. :)

Comment: Well, sure, if you want to go the *really* easy route :)

Comment: I do, yessir, always.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to you how this works:

```
map2_List :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
map2_List f [] _ = []
map2_List f (a:as) bs = map (f a) bs ++ map2_List f as bs
```

Re-write it as a list comprehension, for clarity:

```
map2_List f as bs = concat [ map (f a) bs | a <- as]
                  = [ r | a <- as, r <- map (f a) bs]
                  = [ r | a <- as, r <- [(f a) b | b <- bs]]
                  = [ r | a <- as, r <- [ f a  b | b <- bs]]
                  = [ r | a <- as, b <- bs, r <- [f a b]]
                  = [ f a b | a <- as, b <- bs]
```

and you can see that it is equivalent to the usual imperative nested loop,

```
for a in as :
   for b in bs :
       yield (f a b)
```

and is indeed applying the function `f` on each pair of `a` from `as` and `b` from `bs`, combined in the nested fashion.